# Cross-fade video to itself with FFmpeg for seamless looping

Tags: ffmpeg

I have found some questions&answers concerning cross-fading between two images or videos, but which ffmpeg CLI commands are needed to fade a video with **itself**?

Explanation of the desired effect:

- Some frames (let's say 1 second) are removed from the video's beginning
- Starting in the video's last 1 second, the frames removed from the beginning are faded in over the end frames
- This results in a smooth loop playback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To expand a little on @llogan's answer using the times I was working with:

`-filter_complex "[0]trim=end=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[begin];[0]trim=start=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[end];[end][begin]xfade=wipedown:duration=1:offset=2"`

This is almost exactly what I was looking for (fade a video's end into its own beginning for looping) as well, after messing with the filters to figure out what they actually do. First off, [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Xfade) is a slightly clearer explanation of the xfade filter, which is actually super awesome and I'm stoked to know it exists. Try using one of the more dramatic fades to get a clearer picture of your transition.

Breaking down the filtergraph a bit (the timestamps reflect the 4-second video I was looping):

`-filter_complex`

Call the filtergraph

`"[0]trim=end=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[begin];`

Taking the first input (`[0]`) use the `trim` filter to make the section you want to fade in at the end of the video. Set the `end` of this excerpt to be at second `1` (it could be whatever, this makes a 1-second exerpt). Then use the `setpts` filter to set the timestamp (of the excerpt?) to start at zero. `[begin]` is the arbitrary label for the output of this first filter chain, but you can call it `[thomas]` or whatever.

`[0]trim=start=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[end];`

Now use `trim` to make another input that's actually the entire video, minus the same 1 second that you'll be fading into at the end. This tripped me up a bit until I realized you're setting the end of the first chunk at the same point of the start of the main chunk. This main chunk gets the label `[end]`.

`[end][begin]xfade=fade:duration=1:offset=2"`

Now use the `xfade` filter using the `fade` mode (there are examples of all the others in the link above) to dissolve from `[end]` into `[begin]`. You set the duration of the fade to last `1` second and offset the beginning of the fade at the `2` second mark. Keep in mind, this was a 4-second video that just got the first second basically trimmed and overlaid onto the end, so you now have a 3-second video. You could just as easily left the `[end]` chunk starting at `0` as well (the OP asked for what's described here tho).

Give it an `output.mov` path and you're good to go.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [trim](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#trim), [setpts](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts_002c-asetpts), and [xfade](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#xfade) filters:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]trim=end=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[begin];[0]trim=start=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[end];[end][begin]xfade=fade:duration=0.5:offset=8.5" output.mp4
```

Comment: the offset=8.5 is problematic here as I don't know the video length in general

Comment: Additionally, I can't observe the fade effect in the resulting video, even if I increase the fade duration and set the offset to a smaller value

Comment: @PhilLab 1. [Use `ffprobe` to get duration value](https://superuser.com/questions/650291/how-to-get-video-duration-in-seconds/945604#945604). 2. Show your command and the full log. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60043174/edit) your question to include this info.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get these answers to work.  Processing would stop/pause at frame 75 and keep "running" doing nothing.

This answer worked well, and it worked fast for a longer video:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38189232/901739