# ffmpeg - seamless crossfade loop for the part of video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, cut, cross-fade

I need to apply crossfade to the last X frames of a video with the first X frames in order to obtain a seamless loop, but making this for the necessary part of video.

[Here's the answer for looping the entire video.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38186672/ffmpeg-make-a-seamless-loop-with-a-crossfade)

Currently what I have:
(Whole video duration = 25. Cutted (result) part = 15 sec (from 5 to 20 sec pos). Transition = 1 sec.)

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 5 -to 20 -filter_complex
    "[0]split[body][pre];
     [pre]trim=duration=1,format=yuva420p,fade=d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS+( (15+(5-1)) /TB)[jt];
     [body]trim=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[main];
     [main][jt]overlay"  -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -b:v 2500K output.mp4
```

In this case, everything works, but at the end of the resulting video, a piece from the original video is superimposed, which starts from 0 to 1 second, and not from 4 to 5 seconds of the original video, as it should be.

I read the official ffmpeg documentation, tried some actions on "start/end" parameters for "trim/fade" with changing of "setpts", but I always got just another batch of bugs.

Comment: `ss` and `to` as output options affect the output after filtering. Place them before input and your first setpts should be corrected to account for the setpts of the 2nd trimmed segment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending some more time, I decided to start from something easier for understanding (easier logic). I just remove `-ss`/`-to` and modify the `-filter_complex` by spliting the original video into 3 streams, from which I cut out the corresponding parts. The last 2 streams of the same length I have superimposed on each other using the method from my question. After that, I re-combined them in the correct sequence.

(For clarity, I enclosed variables in more and less signs.)

```
-filter_complex "[0]split=3[var1][var2][var3];
[var1]trim= <cut_start> : (<cut_start> + <duration> - <fade_time>),setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];
[var2]trim= (<cut_start> + <duration> - <fade_time>) : (<cut_start> + <duration>),setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];
[var3]trim= (<cut_start> - <fade_time>) : <cut_start> ,format=yuva420p,fade=start_time= (<cut_start> - <fade_time>) :duration= <fade_time> :alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2];
[v1][v2]overlay[v3];
[v0][v3]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[out]" -map "[out]"
```